# Implementaion of ACS for WCF Service Application

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-security, wcf-client, acs

I'm trying to implement ACS for WCF Service Application(For using Google, Facebook for Authentication). I configured my ACS in Azure Portal and I tried the way of adding STS Reference for WCF Service Application(This is the way generally used of web application). Is this the correct way or do we need to add any more specifications for it?

I have gone through many samples but couldn't understand..

If possible can any one provide a small example with snapshots..

Please help me in right path...

Thanks in Advance...